# Can't access custom properties of linked character

Tags: linked-data

I have a rigged character linked in a new file in Blender 3.1 with "Make Library Override" but i can't access any of the character's custom properties: "Disabled: Can't edit this property from a linked data block."
I already went through the character blend file and made sure, every custom property has the option "make library overridable" checked, but it still isn't working. What am i missing here?

Comment: How did you link the character?  Since 2.90 you need to put the character and the armature into a collection and link the collection, not the individual pieces.

Comment: I did that. The armature and all necessary mesh parts already were in one collection, which i linked in a new file.

Comment: Can you add a blend file to your question that show the problem: A subset of the library file that has a custom property and would fail to link for you? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I can't share the rigged character here and it's too complicated for me to isolate the part that causes problems. One thing i noticed though is, that this seems to be specific to characters rigged with AutoRig Pro because it was the same with a different ARP-character but Rigify characters work without problems.

Comment: Maybe try the ARP forums?  Not a lot of people here use it and without any files to go on, it's unlikely that the rest of us will be able to guess well.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the original rig file. You'll have to edit each property and check *Make Library Overridable*.